Conditional filling of autocomplete dropdown in Django backend with admin_auto_filters
My models.py:
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Funder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    scheme = models.ManyToManyField('Scheme', blank=True, related_name='funders')

class Scheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Project(models.Model):

    funder = models.ForeignKey(Funder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    scheme = ChainedForeignKey(
        Scheme,
        chained_field="funder",
        chained_model_field="funder",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True, null=True, blank=True)

As you can see I'm already using smart-selects for getting only the schemes that belong to that specific funder available in the Project dropdown selection in the admin back-end. smart-selects, though, doesn't take care of what happens in the list_filters section of the Admin.
What I'd like to achieve: have two 'chained' dropdown filters in my Project admin table, where I'm filtering for projects that have a specific funder, and once I've filtered such projects I want to see only the schemes that belong to that specific funder in the schemes dropdown, with the ability of furter filtering the projects with that specific scheme.
My failing attempt so far (admin/py):
from admin_auto_filters.filters import AutocompleteFilter, AutocompleteFilterFactory


class SchemeFilter(
    AutocompleteFilterFactory(
        'new Scheme', 'scheme'
    )
):
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        this_funder = request.GET.get('funder__pk__exact', '')
        if this_funder:
            schemes= Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=this_funder).distinct()
        else:
            schemes = Scheme.objects.none()
        return schemes.values('pk', 'name')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        this_funder = request.GET.get('funder__pk__exact', '')

        if this_funder and Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=this_funder).count():
            return queryset.filter(funder__pk__exact=self.value())

        return queryset.filter(scheme__pk__exact=self.value())

class FunderFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Funder'
    field_name = 'funder'

class ProjectAdmin(NumericFilterModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['title', 'project_number']
    list_filter = [FunderFilter, SchemeFilter,]
[...]

Update I
I think the issue is here:
schemes= Scheme.objects.filter(funder__pk__exact=this_funder).distinct()
I've now added a related_name. Still no luck.
Update II
I realised that I was editing the queryset, whereas I should have worked on the lookups instead. Here's my updated code. I feel I'm so close to finding the solution. It looks like the lookup ifs are ignored and the full list of schemes is always returned.
class SchemeFilter(
    AutocompleteFilterFactory(
        'Scheme', 'scheme'
    )
):
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        this_funder = request.GET.get('funder__pk__exact', '')
        if (this_funder != '' and Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=this_funder).count() > 0):
            schemes= Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=this_funder).distinct()
        elif (this_funder != '' and Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=this_funder).count() == 0):
            schemes = Scheme.objects.none()
        else:
            schemes = Scheme.objects.all()

        return schemes.values('pk', 'name')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        if self.value():
            queryset = queryset.filter(scheme__pk__exact=self.value()).distinct()

        return super().queryset(request, queryset)

Update III
I'm beginning to think that it's a bug of admin_auto_filters. Indeed, if I use the native SimpleListFilter like so:
class TestSchemeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'Test Scheme'
    parameter_name = 'scheme'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        pk = request.GET.get('funder__pk__exact', '')
        if pk and Scheme.objects.filter(funders__pk__exact=pk).count() > 0:
            schemes = Scheme.objects.filter(funders__id__exact=pk)
        else:
            schemes = Scheme.objects.all()
        return [(s.id, s.name) for s in schemes]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        if self.value():
            queryset = queryset.filter(scheme__pk__exact=self.value()).distinct()

I successfully get a list of only the schemes belonging to that funder in the right-hand side.
